# Javascript Object constructor override to stop certain methods be called

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-inheritance

A global object as such “Obj” is created:

```
Obj = {     
   gtm : {},
   method: function(){console.log("Method is called");}
};
```

In some other places `Obj.method()` is used.

My question is can I extend the code for “Obj” in any way to prevent the call to `Obj.method()`. 
I don’t want to rewrite or remove the codes in other places because that would be a lot of changes. Instead, I would like to change the original code so that on some condition I will just not call the method.

Proxy is not an option as Proxy will require me to change the calls in other places as well. And Proxy does not work in IE 11.

Can I rather override the constructor and achieve what I want?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I don't see any way for method to be called at all with this code.

Comment: Any chances to correct the snippet? Currently, none of `$` and `data` is used inside the creation function. And, the `method` is not even attached to returned object.

Comment: @TKoL I have edited the code in the question.

Comment: @WiktorZychla  I have edited the code in the question.

Comment: "Can I rather override the constructor" — There is no constructor in the example.

Comment: @Quentin isn't there an implicit constructor. If not how can I introduce one and just control other methods from that constructor?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the function somewhere else.
2. Write a new function that calls it.
3. Assign that function to the object property.

Such:

```
(function () {
    // IIFE for scope so we don't create another global (`method` on the next line)
    const method = Obj.method;
    const new_method = function() {
        if (your_condition) {
            method();
        }
    };
    Obj.method = new_method;
})();
```

If the value of `this` or any arguments matter, you'll need to pass them along.

e.g.

```
method.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: I wanted something like: ```constructor(){ if(condition){ propagate and execute the called method} else{ do not do anything} }``` is that possible to achieve somehow?

Comment: You have a singleton which you're generating with an object initializer. Since you don't have a `class`, that doesn't make sense. The code in this answer achieves the same end result by rewriting the existing object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but you said

*"Instead, I would like to change the original code so that con some condition I will just not call the method."*

So why not do something like this:

```
Obj = {     
   gtm : {},
   method: function(){
      if (someCondition) return;
      // do rest of the method here
   }
};
```